# Are Bech32 addresses safe for mainnet usage?

Tags: bech32-address

According to github [bitcoin/bips](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips), BIP-173 is still a draft. And i saw today that Electrum wallet start using it.

Is this means that the specs for BIP-173 won't change in the future ? or the final version won't introduce breaking changes to the draft version ?

I just learned about Bech32 addresses this week and this gets me a little confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are. Bech32 addresses allow for native Segwit outputs, which offer higher efficiency and security than the legacy P2SH nested Segwit outputs. https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0173.mediawiki#Reference_implementations has reference implementations in C, C++, JS, Go, Python, Haskell, Ruby, and Rust along with tests courteous of [Pieter Wuille](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/208/pieter-wuille)

Comment: Thanks a lot @satoshi_ghost ! i have been waiting this answer for a long time :D

Comment: Pieter Wuille just moved the BIP from draft to proposed (https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/pull/627).